# Clip geometries in table based upon value

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I have defined a view in postgres that returns a set of polygons and can be queried as follows:-

```
SELECT wkb_geometry, grade_count FROM ng_schema.grade_count_report [sql.where] order by grade_count asc
```

This returns me a set of polygons with varying values of grade_count

What I want to do next is find geometries that overlap and cut out the overlap from the geometry that has the lower grade_count. Where they were equal I would cut the geometry with the largest area.

How best to do this?

UDATE: To be clear when I say "has the lower grade_count" this is the lower grade count of the two intersecting geometries NOT the lower grade_count of all of them as the answer below has calculated.

So I need to find ALL intersections across ALL geometries and clip them all with the LOWEST grade_count of the two losing part of its geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say that this view is called `grade_geom_table`

```
SELECT wkb_geometry, grade_count FROM ng_schema.grade_count_report [sql.where] order by grade_count asc
```

The following query will return you the lowest grade_count with the biggest area:

```
SELECT wkb_geometry FROM grade_geom_table ORDER BY grade_count ASC, ST_Area(wkb_geometry) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Put things together and this will give you this:

```
SELECT
  ST_Difference(grade_geom_table.wkb_geometry, lower_grade.wkb_geometry),
  grade_geom_table.grade_count
FROM
  (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM grade_geom_table ORDER BY grade_count ASC, ST_Area(wkb_geometry) DESC LIMIT 1) as lower_grade,
  grade_geom_table
WHERE
  grade_geom_table.wkb_geometry && lower_grade.wkb_geometry AND
  ST_Intersects(grade_geom_table.wkb_geometry, lower_grade.wkb_geometry)
```

Note that I didn't test this since I don't have your dataset so it's possible that I made a typo or inverted an ASC or DESC. Let me know!

PS: If you didn't create a PostgreSQL view you can simply replace `grade_geom_table` in the above query by:

```
(SELECT wkb_geometry, grade_count FROM ng_schema.grade_count_report [sql.where] order by grade_count asc) as grade_geom_table
```

Comment: That looks to be exactly on the right lines, I just need to add the non-intersecting geometries to it as well

Comment: I've just been testing this and realised it does not answer my problem. I want to clip ALL geometries that intersect, with the lower grade of the two being clipped. The answer only clips those that intersect with a single geometry.  What I need is for a set A=2,B=3,C=3,D=4,E=5 with A intersecting B,D and E then A would be clipped by B,D,E any other intersections would be clipped in a similar manner